# Does Motional EMF depend on the shape of path taken or depends on the shortest distance between given two points?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

> A semi-circular conducting wire of radius 2m is rotated in a uniform magnetic field $B=0.1\text{ T}$ ($\vec k$) about point $O$ with angular speed $\omega=10\text{ rad/s}$ as shown in the figure. The axis of rotation is parallel to $B$. Find the magnitude of the potential difference between point $M$ and point $N$.

[image]

My attempt: I actually tried to perform integration for each arc. Assumed the speed of a small angle and tried to write $\mathrm d\vec E=(\vec V \times \vec B)\cdot\mathrm d\vec l$, but it doesn't prove beneficial as the direction at every point is changing. But in the given solution, they assumed a straight line between
($O$ and $M$), ($O$ and $N$) respectively, treated those parts as rod rotating about $O$, but I can't understand this approach.

Can anyone please explain the concepts we can use in this question or any alternate approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given solution uses the fact that a closed loop that encloses a constant amount of magnetic flux has no e.m.f. Let $\alpha$ denote the path $\overset{\Huge\frown}{OM}$ and $\beta$ the straight line $\overline{OM}$. By Lenz's law,
$$ \oint \mathbf{E}\cdot \text{d}\mathbf{r} = \int_\alpha \mathbf{E}\cdot \text{d}\mathbf{r} - \int_\beta \mathbf{E}\cdot \text{d}\mathbf{r} = V_{\overset{\Huge\frown}{OM}} - V_{\overline{OM}} = -\frac{\text{d}\Phi_\mathbf{B}}{\text{d}t} = 0.$$
Hence, for the purposes of calculating the potential difference between $M$ and $N$, the curved wire $\overset{\Huge\frown}{OM}$ can be replaced by the straight wire $\overline{OM}$. The same reasoning applies for the arc $\overset{\Huge\frown}{ON}$.